# How to take data from access data to Combobox

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, vb.net-2010

```
Public Class AdminP_Time2

    Dim conn As OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
    Dim sql As String
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader

    Private Sub AdminP_Time2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load    
        conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Database.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;")
        conn.Open() 'opens the connection
        sql = "SELECT * FROM LecturerName"
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        If dr.Read = True Then
            ComboBox1.Text = dr("LecturerName")
        End If
```

why my combobox just show me 1 item ? can anyone help me ? i want take my access data to Combobox.

Comment: You probably want to read in a loop and use `ComboBox1.Items.Add()`.  You will save yourself some trouble down the road by creating, using and disposing of Connections and especially DbCOmmand and DataReader objects as you need them.  The last 2 really arent reusable at all

Comment: Fill a DataTable and set that as your `DataSource` for the `ComboBox`... The reason only for 1 item is because you are not looping through the reader..

Comment: Why do you have a table named "LecturerName" and a column named "LecturerName"? Surely you should have a table named "Lecturer" and a column named "Name". It would be fair enough to name the column "LecturerName" but not the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that your own code doesn't work is that you're only reading one record.  You need a loop, e.g.

```
While dr.Read()
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(dr("LecturerName"))
End While
```

That said, your code should look more like this:

```
Using conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Database.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"),
      cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM LecturerName", conn)
    conn.Open()

    Using dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        Dim tbl As New DataTable

        tbl.Load(dr)

        With ComboBox1
            .DisplayMember = "LecturerName"
            .DataSource = tbl
        End With
    End Using
End Using
```

That will load the data into a `DataTable` and bind that to the `ComboBox`.  You should also set the `ValueMember` of the `ComboBox` if you want to be able to access the PK value of the selected record via the `SelectedValue` of the `ComboBox`.  You should also specify what columns you want to retrieve data from rather than using a wildcard unless you genuinely want every column.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good example.

```
Sub TryThis()

Dim db As DAO.Database
   Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
   Dim strSQL As String
   Set db = CurrentDb
   Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("qryStaffListQuery”)

   strSQL = "SELECT tblStaff.* ” & _
                 "FROM tblStaff ” & _
                 "WHERE tblStaff.Office='" & Me.cboOffice.Value & "’ ” & _
                 "AND tblStaff.Department='" & Me.cboDepartment.Value & "’ ” & _
                 "AND tblStaff.Gender='" & Me.cboGender.Value & "’ ” & _
                 "ORDER BY tblStaff.LastName,tblStaff.FirstName;”
End Sub
```

[image]

You can find all details from the link below.

http://www.fontstuff.com/access/acctut17.htm